# How to fold two different types? FP-TS

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I'm learning FP with FP-TS and I just hit a road block:

I have the following function in my repository:

```js
// this is the repository
export const findBook = (id: string) => TaskEither<Error, Option<ParsedBook>>
```

that part is easy and makes sense to me. The issue is when I try to call it from my controller:

```js
// this is the controller
export const getBook = (req: unknown) => Task<string | ParsedBook>
```

Anyways, here's my `getBook` and what I'm trying to do:

```js
const getBook: (req: unknown) => T.Task<string | ParsedBook> = flow(
  getBookByIdRequestV.decode, // returns Either<Errors, GetBookByIdRequest>
  E.fold(
    () => T.of('Bad request!'),
    flow(
      prop('params'),
      prop('id'),
      findBook, // returns TaskEither<Error, Option<ParsedBook>>
      TE.fold(
        () => T.of('Internal error.'),
        O.fold(
          () => T.of('Book not found.'),
          (book) => T.of(book) // this line results in an error
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

The issue is that the above code gives me an error:

```
Type 'ParsedBook' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

I think the issue is that `E.fold` expects the result of `onLeft` and `onRight` to return the same type:

```js
fold<E, A, B>(onLeft: (e: E) => B, onRight: (a: A) => B): (ma: Either<E, A>) => B
```

However, it might not only return a `Task<string>`, but a `Task<ParsedBook>` as well.

I tried using `foldW`, which widens the type, but same error as well.

I don't really know what to do; I feel like the way I am modelling the types in my code are bad?

Here's the Codesandbox if it helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-chandrasekhar-5p2xm?file=/src/index.ts

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get when trying to use `foldW` is because `Task<string> | Task<ParsedBook>` isn’t assignable to `Task<string | ParsedBook>`.

Instead of unwrapping the `TaskEither` using `TE.fold` and then re-wrapping the values in a Task using `T.of`, you could use `T.map` with `E.foldW` instead:

```
import { identity } from "fp-ts/function";

T.map(E.foldW(
  () => "Internal error.",
  O.foldW(() => "Book not found.", identity)
))
```

In fact, there’s an even simpler way to do this using [`O.getOrElseW`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html#getorelsew):

```
T.map(E.foldW(
  () => "Internal error.",
  O.getOrElseW(() => "Book not found.")
))
```

Full code:

```
const getBook: (req: unknown) => T.Task<string | ParsedBook> = flow(
  getBookByIdRequestV.decode,
  E.fold(
    () => T.of("Bad request!"),
    flow(
      prop("params"),
      prop("id"),
      findBook,
      T.map(E.foldW(
        () => "Internal error.",
        O.getOrElseW(() => "Book not found.")
      ))
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice, I'm trying to learn more about FP myself.

I'm not sure if I understood what `getBook` should be doing. But I would keep it's return as a `TaskEither` because it should represent the possibility of failing.

When working with Functors/Monads I think of them like a box. And I want to keep my values save inside the box. If you look up `fold` you will find it listed under destructors, that is because it kind of destroys your box. So avoid `fold`, maybe do it at the end of your computation if you have to.

But how do we do anything with our values if they are stuck inside a box? `map` is our first solution here because we can take a function that acts on values to now act on boxes. But it keeps the box around our values.

We can also swap out the Box with `TE.fromEither` or `TE.fromOption`, which keeps our value save inside its box.

And lastly we can `chain` to keep only one box. Every time a `map` would give us a box in a box, we can change it to `chain`. But the type of box has to align, or you will have to transform it before.

With those in mind I would write `getBook` like this:

```
const getBook2: (req: unknown) => TE.TaskEither<string, ParsedBook> = flow(
  getBookByIdRequestV.decode,
  E.mapLeft(() => 'Bad request!'),
  E.map(({ params }) => params.id),
  TE.fromEither,
  TE.chain(flow(
    findBook,
    TE.mapLeft(() => 'internal error.')
  )),
  TE.chain(TE.fromOption(() => 'Book not found.'))
)
```

Hope this helps and I'm still learning myself. So let me know if there is a better way.